# Vue.js - Restore input value if model rejects changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a text input that allow user to type a number with maximum of 3 digits after decimal point:

```
<v-text-field type="text" :value="num" @change="changeNum($event)" />
<p>{{ num }}</p>

...

export default {
  data: () => ({
    num: 0
  }),
  methods: {
    changeNum(e) {
      let v = parseFloat(e);
      if (!isNaN(v)) {
        this.num = parseFloat(v.toFixed(3));
      }
    }
  }
};
```

If I type `'123.456'`, then `num = 123.456`.
If I append text `'789'`, then input will contain `123.456789` but `num = 123.456`. So, user may think that the changes have been applied, but it is not...

How can I force the input to update, if `changeNum` fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve your use case by using only `v-model.lazy` to change data after leaving the textfield, and `watch` property which save the old and new value that allows us to control the typed value after focusing somewhere else.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    num: 0
  }),

  watch: {
    num(newv, oldv) {
      let v = parseFloat(newv);
      if (!isNaN(v)) {
        this.num = parseFloat(v.toFixed(3));
      } else {
        this.num = oldv;
      }

    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Vue.delete">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">

    <input type="text" v-model.lazy="num" />
    <p>out: {{ num }}</p>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

`@change` won't fire until you change focus to something else.  To ensure you evaluate the input as you type, use `@input` instead.  It will fire with every keystroke.

Also, keep track of the last value so you can reset:

```
<v-text-field type="text" :value="num" @input="changeNum($event)" />
<p>{{ num }}</p>

...

export default {
  data: () => ({
    num: 0,
    lastNum: 0
  }),
  methods: {
    changeNum(e) {
      let v = parseFloat(e);
      if (!isNaN(v)) {
        this.num = parseFloat(v.toFixed(3));
        this.lastNum = this.num;
      }
      else {
        this.num = this.lastNum;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You don't understand, the problem is not in the type of event. `changeNum` shouldn't update the model, if the input has an invalid value. I want to reset the input value to the last valid model value, when the current input value is invalid. For example, let the current input value is `'1.234'`. Then I type `'1.234safsaf'` and click outside to fire `@change`. I want the displayed input value to be reset to `'1.234'`, because `'1.234safsaf'` is invalid.

Comment: So you are ok with a mismatch while typing, but want to reset once the input loses focus.  That wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `$forceUpdate` should solve your issue ..

```
methods: {
    changeNum(e) {
      let v = parseFloat(e);
      if (!isNaN(v)) {
        this.num = parseFloat(v.toFixed(3));
        this.$forceUpdate();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but it does not work for me because I use `v-text-field` component from Vuetify.js, and `$forseUpdate` does not affect all child components, only the instance itself and child components with inserted slot content.